# What to do after training MNIST dataset

Tags: tensorflow

I have trained a CNN using the MNIST dataset on tensorflow. I have got 98% accuracy on the test dataset. But now i want to test the trained CNN on real world images. So I drew digits in paint and gave it to the CNN. But it does not give the right class. 
for example: for 5 it says 8, for 0 it says 8 
I have attached the code. I doubt that the way I am predicting the number on my custom input is wrong.

Rest of the code is from here [CNN code by HVASS](https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/02_Convolutional_Neural_Network.ipynb)

```py
# custom input
imageName = sys.argv[1] 
image = imread(imageName,flatten=True)
example = imresize(image,(img_size,img_size))
example = example.reshape(1,img_size_flat)
print example.shape

prediction=tf.argmax(y_pred,1)
print "predictions", prediction.eval(feed_dict={x: example}, 
session=session)
```

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4dQw.png)
[imag2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhc1j.png)

Comment: If you're input is correct (correctly scaled (0-255, -1-1 or 0-1 depending of your training format), 1 gray scale with  black background,...). it's possible that you overfitt on the mnist dataset and that your network isn't able to overfit to new examples

Comment: But I have a separate train and test dataset. And on the test dataset I get 98%  accuracy. So its not overfitting. I have adjusted my input in accordance with the MNIST.

Comment: What I meant is that every dataset has it's own bias. Even if you're able to generalize to you're mnsit testing set, you may not be able to generalize to other digits which are too different from the ones you trained your model on.

Comment: Can you post a couple of the images that you generated?

Comment: I have added the images as links

Comment: if you look at your training set all your images are grayscale and the original images are written with white ink in a black sheet of paper, however you are trying to test it in the opposite black ink, white paper. If you try digits written in black sheet with white ink(color), it should perform in the scale of your test set accuracy.